# Pyodbc Issue with Teradata

Tags: linux, teradata, pyodbc

Getting below error while connecting with Teradata from pyodbc in Linux

> ('632', '[632] 523 630 (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Details below:

```
Connection String
DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=;UID=;PWD=;QUIETMODE=YES;    
Pyodbc Version:pyodbc-2.1.8    
Python Version: 2.7.3
Teradata below:   
RELEASE 14.10.03.07    
VERSION 14.10.03.06    
Linux Host Details: 2.6.39-400.17.2.el5uek
```

Please help.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the actual code that you are having a problem with? Some more context may help.

Answer (score 3):

Need to export ODBCINI path, its done

> export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/odbc.ini