# How to resolve pythonodbc issue with Teradata in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, teradata, pyodbc

I am getting non text error with Pythonodbc in Teradata Ubuntu

```
`saranya@saranya-XPS-8500:~/Desktop$ python test.py`
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in 
    conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=**.**..**;UID=*****;PWD=*****;', ANSI=True, autocommit=True)

**pyodbc.Error: ('632', '[632] 523 630 (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')**

The solution provided in post [Pyodbc Issue with Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621179/pyodbc-issue-with-teradata) is not helping.

Also,
exporting ODBCINI, NLSPATH, LD_LIBRARY_HOME,ODBC_HOME values are not helping either.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similarly obscure response, which seems like it could be related to any number of problems while setting up the connection.  Working on a linux box, I was able to get it to work by setting up a DSN.  To do this, create a file in your home directory `~/.odbc.ini` similar to the following:

```
[ODBC] 
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/15.10
Trace=0
TraceDll=/opt/teradata/client/15.10/lib64/odbctrac.so
TraceFile={trace location, ie. /home/yourusername/odbctrace/trace.log}
TraceAutoStop=0

[ODBC Data Sources]
testdsn=tdata.so

[testdsn]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/15.10/lib64/tdata.so
Description=Teradata database
DBCName={ip address of your database}
LastUser=
Username={your database's username}
Password={your database's password}
Database={database to use}
DefaultDatabase={default database to use}
```

Note: you have to fill out the above `{xxx}` with your values.  I've used the default library installation values for the teradata odbc drivers on linux.

Now, with this DSN file set up, set the environment variable

```
export ODBCINI=/home/yourusername/.odbc.ini
```

Then you should be able to run the script

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling = False
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=testdsn')
```

Even better, if you are connecting to Teradata, install the python teradata module with:

```
sudo pip install teradata
```

Once this is installed, you can create connections with the following script

```
import teradata
from datetime import *

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="Generic Name" + 
    datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d:%H:%M:%S"), version="1.0", 
    configureLogging = True, logConsole=True)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", DSN="testdsn")
```

By setting the `configureLogging=True` and `logConsole=True` options, you can output additional debugging information.

This is at least what worked for me!

#### Erroneous Errors

At the time of writing, the Teradata ODBC drivers in Python output erroneous error messages.  If you drop a table that exists, it says:

```
Error:  (3807, u"[42S02] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Object 'database.table_name' does not exist. ")
```

And if you create a table that does not previously exist, it says:

```
Error:  (3803, u"[42S01] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Table 'database.table_name' already exists. ")
```